# How should one tell if it's kubuntu or ubuntu installed?

Tags: kubuntu

How can I tell if it's ubuntu or kubuntu that is installed ?

I will install `chmsee` on ubuntu , but `kchmviewer` on kubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` should tell you what Desktop Environment is in use.  ubuntu == some gtk based DE, unity by default. The others I don't know off-hand, but that environment variable is there for exactly this purpose.

Comment: Ubuntu could also be GNOME.  Unless you see KDE as the desktop environment, or LXDE, or XFCE, it's Ubuntu

Comment: True...I'll edit to address that, but either way both gnome and unity are gtk based toolkits, which is what the OP was after

Answer (score 0):

Other options include:

- as mentioned, examine `$DESKTOP_SESSION` or `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` to see if they indicate which desktop env is running (KDE / Kubuntu may show `plasma`), but this may be ambiguous and/or change over the years;
- via the desktop, hit the "super" key (i.e,. "windows" key) and search for "about", which will show system details from the `settings` application (whether it's from KDE or Gnome, etc);
- install `wmctrl` (via `sudo apt install wmctrl`) and run: `wmctrl -m` to see if it reports `KWin` for Kubuntu, or e.g., `GNOME Shell` for Ubuntu (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116569/7832 )